# Configuring ant to run unit tests. Where should libraries be? How should classpath be configured? avoiding ZipException

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm trying to run my junit tests using ant.  The tests are kicked off using a JUnit 4 test suite. If I run this direct from Eclipse the tests complete without error.  However if I run it from ant then many of the tests fail with this error repeated over and over until the junit task crashes.

```
    [junit] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    [junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114)
    [junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:131)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.nextElement(AntClassLoader.java:130)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CollectionUtils$CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CollectionUtils.java:198)
    [junit]     at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CompoundEnumeration.java:43)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.checkForkedPath(JUnitTask.java:1128)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeAsForked(JUnitTask.java:1013)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:834)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1785)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:785)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

my test running task is as follows:

```
    <target name="run-junit-tests" depends="compile-tests,clean-results">
        <mkdir dir="${test.results.dir}"/>
        <junit failureproperty="tests.failed" fork="true" showoutput="yes" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="test.run.path" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <test name="project.AllTests" todir="${basedir}/test-results" />
        </junit>
        <fail if="tests.failed" message="Unit tests failed"/>
    </target>
```

I've verified that the classpath contains the following as well as all of the program code and libraries:

```
ant-junit.jar
ant-launcher.jar
ant.jar
easymock.jar
easymockclassextension.jar
junit-4.4.jar
```

I've tried debugging to find out which ZipFile it is trying to open with no luck, I've tried toggling *includeantruntime* and *fork* and i've tried running ant with *ant -lib test/libs* where test/libs contains the ant and junit libraries.

Any info about what causes this exception or how you've configured ant to successfully run unit tests is gratefully received.

ant 1.7.1 (ubuntu), java 1.6.0_10, junit 4.4

Thanks.

**Update - Fixed**
Found my problem. I had included my classes directory in my path using a fileset as opposed to a pathelement this was causing .class files to be opened as ZipFiles which of course threw an exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found my problem. I had included my classes directory in my path using a **fileset** as opposed to a **pathelement** this was causing .class files to be opened as ZipFiles which of course threw an exception.

Answer (score 9):

This error is caused specifically because the class path contains explicit references to one or more [files] that are not JAR's. The reference to "error in opening zip file" is of course that a JAR is in effect a ZIP file where as other files [JUNIT] has found like class files are *not* and as such do not have a zip format. So the class path should contain only explicit references to JAR [files] and/or the names of the [directories] where other resources like class files are to be found.

So when building up your class path (in ANT) use:

```
<path id="proj.class.path">
    <pathelement location="c:/my/project/root" />       :one for each of the [directories] where class files, log4j property files and other resources etc are to be found
    <fileset refid="my.file.set">                   :to describe all the explicit JAR [files] that need to be on the class path.
</path>
```

where

```
<fileset id="my.file.set" dir="c:/where/i/keep/my/jars">
    <filename name="myjar1.jar" />
    <filename name="myjar2.jar" />
    <filename name="myjar3.jar" />
</fileset>
```

or

NOTE: When using wild cards like `[**/*]` in  you need to make sure the wild card is not matching files that are not JAR files

```
<fileset id="my.file.set" dir="c:/where/i/keep/my/jars">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is an issue with paths.

Check following error source:

- classpath: print out the classpath variable in a junit test, run it from eclipse and ant, so you can compare them
- Check your project for absolute paths. Probably, ant uses other path prefixes than eclipse.

Some more information would help to help :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for this information. I just want to add some tip from my experience. I have the same problem with junit as you when junit tryes to open license*.txt files in lib folder where *.jar resides.(Ivy resolve process puts them here) So

```
<path id="lib.path.id">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**.jar"/>
</path>
```

helps too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian, this will make JUnit (and some other libs) always available for Ant:

```
sudo apt-get install ant-optional
```