# ZipException while converting to dex with Ant, in eclipse it works ok

Tags: android, ant, dex

I have a project that builds ok in Eclipse but throws a ZipException when executing "ant debug". The output is the following (paths and project name excluded)

```
    -dex:
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/.../Android/[folder]/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:206)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
       [dx] 1 error; aborting

BUILD FAILED
/home/.../android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:818: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:820: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:832: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:278: null returned: 1
```

This project references a library project which references another library project. So

Project A -> Project B -> Project C

To me, the weird part is that installing from eclipse everything works perfectly, but I need to be able to build the project from Ant.

I've googled for answers without success. Similar questions in SO that didn't help

[How do I fix this ZipException while compiling an Android project on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935837/how-do-i-fix-this-zipexception-while-compiling-an-android-project-on-jenkins)

[Configuring ant to run unit tests. Where should libraries be? How should classpath be configured? avoiding ZipException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461417/configuring-ant-to-run-unit-tests-where-should-libraries-be-how-should-classpa)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I get the same issue after upgrading the SDK Tools from 16 to 19.

Comment: I gave up on using Android's Ant and created my own, less powerful but it did what I wanted. Also, if I remember well I eliminated the dependency between Project B and Project C and placed a "Project C.jar" in Project A. Wow, what a mess of a comment, sorry I can't help a lot

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error while dexing. I found that a corrupted `.jar` file in an included android library project was causing this issue.

Fixing the corrupted `.jar` file in the included android library project fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone! =D

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm not working on this project anymore, but if people vote this up, I'll tick it as the accepted answer, even tho I don't think that was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem in my project. I found that running ant with the debug flag '-d' dumps the info needed to diagnose the problem. Ant will dump the exact dx command to the console and it looks something like this:

```
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing '/Users/cliff/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/dx' with arguments:
'--dex'
'--output'
'/Users/cliff/Src/myproject/myproject-app/bin/classes.dex'
'/Users/cliff/Src/myproject/myproject-app/bin/classes'
'/Users/cliff/Src/myproject/myproject-config/bin/classes.jar'
```

In my case, one of the dependent projects (myproject-config) had not been built so myproject-config/bin/classes.jar was missing. I walked into the myproject-config/ folder, ran "ant debug" then went back and was able to successfully build my project